# No errors but when i execute it, it is showing a.exe is not running

Tags: c, queue, exe

I made a queue ADT program, and it has no error, but when I run this code, it shows that a.exe has stopped working.
I use Windows 7 with i5 processor.
Please explain the problem.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_info
{
    void*dataptr;
    struct node_info*next;
}node;

typedef struct 
{
    node* f;
    node* r;
    int count;
}queue;

queue*createq()
{
    queue*qp;
    qp=(queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
    if(!qp)
        return NULL;
    qp->count=0;
    qp->f=NULL;
    qp->r=NULL;
    return qp;
}

int enq(queue*qp,void*data)
{
    node*temp;
    temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(!temp)
        return 0;
    temp->dataptr=data;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(qp->count==0)
        qp->f=temp;
    else
        qp->r->next=temp;
    qp->r=temp;
    (qp->count)++;
    return 1;
}

void*deq(queue*qp)
{
    if(qp->count==0)
        return 0;
   node*temp;
   void*dout;
   temp=qp->f;
   dout=temp->dataptr;
   qp->f=temp->next;
   if(qp->count==1)
        qp->r=NULL;
    (qp->count)--;
    return dout;
}

void displayq(queue*qp)
{
    node*temp=qp->f;
    if(qp->count==0)
        printf("queue is empty");
    else
    { 
        printf("%d",*(int*)temp->dataptr);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

int main (queue*qp)
{
    int ele,choice;
    printf("\nEnter\n1.enqueue\n2.dequeue\n3.display\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    while(1)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: 
                printf("enter the element to insert\n");
                scanf("%d",&ele);
                if(enq(qp,&ele))
                printf("%d has been inserted",*(int*)qp->r->dataptr);
                else
                printf("element not inserted");
            case 2:
                if(qp->count==0)
                printf("queue is empty");
                printf("%d is removed",*(int*)(deq(qp)));
            case 3:
                displayq(qp);
        } 
    }
}
```

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gay8c.png)

Comment: No Errors? If your compiler doesn't puke all over that `int main(queue*)` definition you need a different toolchain. Also, turn up your warnings and treat those as errors as well. [Example here](https://godbolt.org/z/GKMrjWbzz).

Comment: No `break;` on any of the cases so they'll all fall through.

Comment: Seems to "enqueue" (repeatedly) the same address of the same local variable.... (Not a big problem owning to the lack of `break` as pointed out by @RetiredNinja)

Answer (score 4):

### Incorrect definition of `main`

The compiler did emit meaningful warnings, but you decided to ignore them.

Unless this declaration,

```
int main(queue *qp)
```

is provided and documented by a certain implementation, it is invalid.

---

From C11:

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
> implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
> defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

```
int main (void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
> names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
> declared):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

---

Always compile with warnings enabled, and consider warnings as errors.

---

### To cast or not to cast?

Regarding casting the result of `malloc` and family:

It is redundant and might hide a bug. These functions returns a generic `void` pointer, or `void *`, that is automatically promoted to the correct type.

---

### Fall-through:

Every `case` in a `switch` requires a `break` statement or you risk fall-through. (Assuming fall-through is not intentional)

From C11:

> 6.8.6.3 The break statement
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 A break statement shall appear only in or as a switch body or loop
> body.
>
> Semantics
>
> 2 A break statement terminates execution of the smallest enclosing
> switch or iteration statement.

---

### `scanf()` returns a value:

`scanf()` returns the number of elements it has successfully processed and converted. You should check if it succeeded.

*Aside:* Space-bar makes for readability, use it. As is, your code is unreadable and it's hard to decipher where a potential bug might be.